# Todd class of diagonal embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading Huybrechts' book on Fourier-Mukai transforms, in particular the chapter concerning the passage to cohomology.

Here I found the following claim: let $i:X\to X\times X$ be the diagonal embedding, then $i^*\sqrt{Todd_{X\times X}}=Todd_X$.

Here $Todd_X=Todd(T_X)$ is the Todd class of the tangent bundle $T_X$ of $X$.

My question is: why is it true?

*What I have done/thought.* I think that it should be easier to show that $i^*Todd_{X\times X}=Todd_X^2$. Using the definition of Todd class (cf. Hartshorne, Appendix on Intersection Theory for example) I could prove that in the general situation $X\times Y$ one has
$$(*)\quad Todd_{X\times Y}=Todd(p^*T_X)\cdot Todd(q^*T_Y)$$
where $p$ and $q$ are the natural projections.

The problem now is that Todd classes don't behave well under pullback, i.e. the Todd of the pullback is not the pullback of the Todd. Anyway, if it were true in this specific situation, then we have done. I do not know if it does hold and I cannot see why it should a priori. Therefore I thought that this approach may be wrong. I tried something else, but without any result..

**Aside**: is there any wider collection of cases $i:Z\to X\times Y$ where one can express the pullback of the Todd class of $X\times Y$ in terms of Todd class of $Z$? For example we can see the situation above as a special incidence variety (and actually I am asking because I am mainly interested in generalising this to incidence varieties).

To be honest I think that the solution to the case of diagonal embedding should point out the answer (or a counter-example) to the question in the aside box, so I am mainly interested in that question.

Any hint, reference, advice, solution is very welcome.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:** As pointed out from the comments below the answer, the Todd class does commute with pullback. In particular this means that the equality $(*)$ is probably the best we can reach without any further geometric property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todd class is multiplicative --- if $E \cong E_1 \oplus E_2$ then $Todd(E) = Todd(E_1)\cdot Todd(E_2)$. On the other hand, $i^*T_{X \times X} \cong T_X \oplus T_X$. Thus 
$$
i^*(Todd(T_{X\times X})) = Todd(i^*T_{X\times X}) = Todd(T_X \oplus T_X) = Todd(T_X) \cdot Todd(T_X).
$$

Comment: Dear Sasha, thank you for this answer. Here you are moving the pullback inside the Todd class. As I said in the post I think this is not the case in general, or am I wrong?

Comment: Dear Cla: you are wrong. The Todd class is a combination of Chern classes, which are natural, and pullbacks are ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Dear Nefertiti: ok, I see it now. I was misled from the definition of Todd for line bundles as $c1/(1-e^{-c_1})$, but of course this gives a linear combination of Chern classes.. thank you!